# Keras: how to reuse weights in encoder-decoder?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Simple encoder-decoder architecture:

```
input = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
output = input
output = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='same', use_bias=False)(output)
output = Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=3, padding='same', use_bias=False)(output)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
print(model.summary())
```

Output:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 32, 32, 3)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 16)        432
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 32, 32, 3)         432
=================================================================
Total params: 864
Trainable params: 864
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I want the same weights in `Conv2D` and `Conv2DTranspose` is it possible in Keras?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, especially given that the two layers have different numbers of filters (16 and 3 in your case).

Comment: I think it's possible 1st is from 3 to 16 and 2nd is from 16 to 3, so the order just need to be inverted, hence the name - Transposed Convolution, also look at the number of parameters they are the same.